# How to enter char* in C?

Tags: c, arrays, input, char, scanf

Its a simple input that I want to make for char*. Why is this not working?
It throws me an exception that I can't resolve..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

char* GetCharSeq()
{
    char *s = (char*)malloc(100);

    scanf_s("%s", s);

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char* charseq;

    charseq = GetCharSeq();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but for system header files you should use angle-brackets like e.g. `#include <stdio.h>`, and in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: if you get an exception, it makes sense to post it aswell

Comment: You should always check return codes (e.g. `scanf_s`'s). What is the actual exception?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It might not be the real problem for his exception. And casting will not harm as well.

Comment: @AnishSharma The casting *can* do harm, that's the problem. Read the second point in the accepted answer. And it's definitely not the source of the problem here, for that I have added an answer (also note the starting disclaimer in the comment about it being unrelated to the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your code

```
char* GetCharSeq()
{
    char *s = (char*)malloc(100);

    gets(s);

    return s;
}
```

This will work.

Comment: It will work if you enter no more than 99 characters, but is unsafe for that very reason!

Comment: Well we can change the value of the `malloc()` argument to any number we want. Will that not do?

Answer (score 4):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code. You have it because you provide to few arguments to the [`scanf_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function.

For every string argument, you need to provide not only the destination string but also the size of the string. So change your call to

```
scanf_s("%s", s, 100);
```

Comment: How does it compile/link with a mismatched parameter list?

Comment: @MartinJames for the same reason `printf("%s");` will compile and link.

Comment: @MartinJames Because the `...` in the prototype means there's a variable number of arguments, and the compiler has no way of knowing the exact amount. Some compilers can figure it out by parsing the format string and will give warnings for such problems, but it's just a warning and technically legal C.

Comment: `scanf_s()` will only compile on a PC. He should rather use `fgets()` as it is a single string he wants to receive.